# (SPO) How to open Notebook (left navigation link) in client apps instead of Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, onenote

So I've activated the "open in client apps" site collection feature on the site collection that I want. Now in the left navigation bar we also have a "Notebook" link, that refers to the OneNote file in our site collection "Site Assets" library. This is for Modern UI btw.

When I click this link, it opens in one note online, but I want it to open in my client app of OneNote. How can I set this?

When I go to the "Site Assets" document library, where the one note file is located, and click on the one note file itself, it will open in client app (as my features are set correctly to open all documents in client app). So I guess it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

If the OneNote file is opened in the OneNote online, then you could click “Edit in OneNote” to open the file in the OneNote client application.

And per my test in my SharePoint online environment, I add the link of the OneNote file in the left navigation, then when click the link of the OneNote file, it will download the link of the OneNote file.

[image]

Then the new experience is the new feature. And it will be improved in the future.